# Launch function after init function Qt - Pyside

Tags: qt, pyside

I have a little problem in my script. I would like ton run a function after the init function is made (so after that my frame is display on my screen) to interect my frame.

How can I do that? I don't find any informations because the frame is always display after the init function and no one launch functions automatticaly after the initiation.

Comment: Just after creating a `QApplication`, you can send a signal, but make sure that it is connected as 'QueuedConnection'. Then the slot will be invoked after `app.exec()`. Don't know how it looks in Python.

Comment: The problem is my function need to interecat with the window. What I need is to launch automatically a function after the windows is display but still interact with. All solutions I have tested was either after closign the window of before display it

Comment: @Max_xaM. You cannot interact with anything until the event-loop has started - which was the point of Velcan's suggestion. Why don't you try it?